# Suggestions for obtaining Google search results and cleaning HTML tags

Tags: python, html, nlp

I am working on a project to get Google search web pages and then clean HTML tags to obtain pure text content.

Any suggestion for available tools (esp. Python tools)

many thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: Keep searching for HTML Parsing and Python.  For example http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+parsing+%5Bpython%5D has lots and lots of hints as to how to proceed.

Comment: I am curious about one thing... Are you deliberately not using Google's Custom Search API? It would get you a more stable set of results than th HTML of Search Results, the format of which is not guaranteed to remain identical request after request.

Comment: My goal is to get the web pages found by Google and extract their text content. I am very new to Google Custom Search API (and will study it tonight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a nice suite [BootCat](http://bootcat.sslmit.unibo.it/).

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out [Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern), which is a Python web mining module providing a suite of text retrieval, analysis, and viz tools. I haven't personally used it but looks powerful.

*Module pattern.web is a web toolkit that bundles various API's (Google, Gmail, Bing, Twitter, Wikipedia, Flickr) with a robust HTML parser and web spider. Its purpose is to retrieve online content in an easy-to-use, uniform way.*

Comment: Thanks John, I noticed this from Twitter but didn't link it to my task.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in one that's actually pretty quick, found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html).  There's also a really powerful one called [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) that offers additional functionality, especially for HTML scraping.

However, I also have to ask why not use the search API?

Comment: Just found a cool python script [link](http://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/google-search-python/) It provides a quite easy way to get searching results from Google. Also, author warned us not work on the back of corporation proxy since Google only allows 100 custom searches per account per day.